# undefined is not an object( evaluating 'state.selected.clip.clip') getting this error using Api in react Native

Tags: react-native

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Video } from 'expo-av';
import { StyleSheet, View,Text, TextInput, ScrollView, Image, TouchableHighlight, Modal, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const apiurl = 'https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size=5';
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    s: 'Enter a movie ...',
    results: [],
    selected: [],
  });
  const search = () => {
    axios(apiurl + '&search=' + state.s).then(({data}) => {
      let results = data.results;
      console.log(results);
      setState(prevState => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          results: results,
        };
      });
    });
  };
  const openPopup = slug => {
    axios('https://api.rawg.io/api/games/' + slug).then(({data}) => {
      let result = data;
      console.log(result);
      setState(prevState => {
        return {...prevState, selected: result};
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text> Game Search</Text>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={text =>
          setState(prevState => {
            return {
              ...prevState,
              s: text,
            };
          })
        }
        value={state.s}
        onSubmitEditing={search}
      />
      <ScrollView>
        {state.results.slice(0, 1).map(result => (
          <TouchableHighlight
            key={result.slug}
            onPress={() => openPopup(result.slug)}>
            <View>
              <Image
                source={{uri: result.background_image}}
                style={{
                  width: 250,
                  height: 250,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}
                resizeMode="cover"
              />
              <Text>{result.name}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
      <Modal
        animationType="fade"
        transparent={false}
        visible={typeof state.selected.name != 'undefined'}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View>
            <Text>{state.selected.name}</Text>
            <Image
              source={{uri: state.selected.background_image}}
              style={{
                margin: 20,
                width: '90%',
                height: 300,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
              }}
              resizeMode="cover"
            />
            <Video
              source={{uri: state.selected.clip.clip}}
              rate={1.0}
              volume={1.0}
              resizeMode="cover"
              shouldPlay
              isLooping
              style={{width: 300, height: 300}}
            />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <Button
          onPress={() =>
            setState(prevState => {
              return {...prevState, selected: {}};
            })
          }
          title="Close"
        />
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}
```

> Whenever I run it, it gives me this error message for the clip otherwise don't get an error message for the image or name or anything else. Does anyone know how to solve it? It's a simple app and all the codes are in App.js
> Here I have attached the image of the error that I am getting. I am using RawG API to create a simple Game-search app
> [Screenshot of that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbPaE.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the case where `state.selected.clip` is `null` or `undefined`. You can do that like this:

```
{
  state.selected.clip && (
    <Video
      source={{uri: state.selected.clip.clip}}
      rate={1.0}
      volume={1.0}
      resizeMode="cover"
      shouldPlay
      isLooping
      style={{width: 300, height: 300}}
    />
  );
}
```

Problems will occur when you haven't selected anything yet or if there is a game that doesn't have a clip. So you shouldn't render the `Video` component if this value is not properly set.

Comment: If my answer solved the problem, please accept my answer.